# Confusing OpenCart Error Messages

Tags: permissions, e-commerce, file-permissions, opencart

I have installed open cart on my website, and when I go to the admin CMS part of the system, I get various error message:

```
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/image/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\admin\controller\common\home.php on line 59
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/image/cache/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\admin\controller\common\home.php on line 76
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\admin\controller\common\home.php on line 93
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/download/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\admin\controller\common\home.php on line 110
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/logs/test) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\admin\controller\common\home.php on line 127
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583267) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583325) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583351) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583503) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583609) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583611) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
Warning: unlink(D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store/system/cache/cache.store.1322583630) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Websites\sotasolutions\completeoffice\completeoffice.co.uk\www\store\system\library\cache.php on line 50
```

I have changed permissions site wide and still I get the error messages.

Please can someone help. It is really annoying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's happening, you need to give permission to allow the apache user delete privileges. I'm guessing you're on IIS?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you configure an IIS machine's file permissions, but that is definitely what it is. Have you made sure that the files and the containing folder are all set with permissions to delete it

Answer (score 0):

Should give full permission for the directory **image,cache and logs** finally refresh that page